# Are workspaces first class citizens of TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, workspace

Are TYPO3 workspaces full TYPO3 citizens that are actively developed or are they rather an outdated concept, that TYPO3 just can't get rid of for reasons of compatibility?

Please include the history of the concept of workspaces, to corroborate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: I can not answer the question "Are workspaces first class citizens of TYPO3?". This need to be answered by a TYPO3 core developer?

The core API documentation explains the basic concept:

> TYPO3 CMS provides a feature called "workspaces", whereby changes can be made to the content of the web site without affecting the currently visible (live) version. Changes can be previewed and go through an approval process before publishing.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Workspaces/Index.html

**Personal expirence**

I have no expirence with workspaces on current stable versions of TYPO3 (9.x / 8.x). 
My expirence with workspaces go´s back to TYPO3 4.5 and 6.2. 
They worked out of the box with all core elements. 
And after adjusting some configuration inside project specific extensions, 
the feature worked by using extbase based repositories.

**Personal conclusion**

My personal opionen is: avoid enable workspaces till its required in project.

Downsides:

- More complexity inside the database.

  - Makes finding bugs/testing more time intensive.
  - If you need to build a custom SQL query, you need to pay close attention to the implementation of workspaces and understand in detail.
- More complexity for the editors.
- 3rd party extensions might not work anymore if they dont use Core API.

Comment: Yes, only some extensions support workspaces. Hence workspaces are rarely used. The agencies I know, prefer staging servers. It's not just a chicken and egg problem. To support workspaces in an extension is quite complex. It requires to handle ten additional database fields per table. A quote from the workspaces documentation itself: "However, when other fields are involved in the where clause it gets dirty."